# Is there an alternative way to program an ESC besides using the firmware?

Tags: flight-controller, esc

I am currently trying to build a drone that has 8 motors (and thus 2 4-in-1 ESCs). The ESC model that I am currently using is the Holybro Tekko32 F4. I am also using a pixhawk as my flight controller.

The issue that I am running into is that when I arm the drone, the motors automatically start spinning, even at zero throttle. I am trying to fix it so that the motors don't spin when you arm it and only start spinning when you increase the throttle up. In order to do that, I've discovered that I need to directly program the ESCs. The Tekko32 ESC that I have uses the BLHeli_32 firmware which can be used to set the minimum throttle setting. You can program the ESCs using an app on a computer and connecting through the flight controller.

However, I can't seem to get the BLHeli_32 firmware to work. I think it has to do with the fact that BLHeli_32 requires betaflight on the flight controller and the flight controller that I currently have doesn't support betaflight. Is there a way that I can program the ESCs without using the firmware that it came with? I'd rather not buy another flight controller that supports betaflight since I spent a good chunk of time already programming the pixhawk in Qgroundcontrol.